# Outlook web app center table

Tags: outlook, html-email, outlook-web-app

I have a very simple html email structure:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        This is where my content goes.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've used this structure for years and it always worked in various email clients because it's so basic.

But in the Outlook Web App it doesn't center the inner table.

It adds style="text-align:center" to the td with align="center". But style="text-align:center" only centers text, no tables. So the inner table aligns left in the OWA.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Some sort of remark on the progress of this would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

This is the second Outlook web app question in the last few days, which makes me wonder if outlook changed something in the way they interpret the html.

Hopefully there is a solution, here are a couple of ideas to try:

- add `width="100%"` to your affected `<td>`
- Try adding `align="center"` to the inner table
- wrap a `<span>` around your inner table, it may work with `text-align:center;`
- add `style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;"` to your inner table, or wrap a div around it and add it to that.

That is all I can think of at the moment, let me know if any work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to why this is the case, but you could try using the center tag `<center>`

Answer (score 0):

Most of solutions will not work. In my case fix was simple, just wrap table by other table and put text center in td as John suggest. Simple snippet:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="100%" align="center">

... content ...

 </td></tr></table>
```